# PuTTY Key via Connection>SSH>Auth>Credentials does not "take"

Tags: ssh, putty

When I add the Key in the proper location, the "Open" button at the bottom is unresponsive, thus the key cannot be opened.  No warnings, just non-responsive.  This is occurring on a work laptop and also on a personal system.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That button doesn't open the key – it opens the whole SSH connection, so it only works if you have the server address filled in in the 1st section. (There is no additional step needed to "open" the key; it's enough to have the path filled in.)

(If you're planning to save the key address as a default, you don't need to use 'Open' yet – instead go back to the 1st section, select "Default Session" and click 'Save'.

Or, don't specify it here at all – you can double-click the key file or add it to 'shell:startup' to load it into the "key agent" where PuTTY will find it automatically.)

Comment: that's right.  server address needed to be specified.